# PHP empty field validation

Tags: php, validation

I have a enrollment form where users have to input there address. I am using PHP for validation and currently I check to make sure the field is not empty. Here is my code:

```
if (empty($_POST['address'])) {
    $msg = 'You must enter an address' ;
} else {
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags(trim($_POST['address']))) ;
}
```

Now the problem is that is the user enters in a "blank" space by pressing the spacebar the filed passes validation. What I need is a way to make sure the user actually typed in a city and not just a blank space or a couple of blank spaces.

Comment: Just `trim` variable before you validate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already use `trim()` on the insert, why not call it once in the beginning, and test that value?

```
$user_address = trim($_POST['address']);

if (empty($user_address)) {
    $msg = 'You must enter an address' ;
} else {
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags($user_address)) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($_POST['address']) || strlen(trim($_POST['address']))==0){
    $msg = 'You must enter an address' ;
}else {
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags(trim($_POST['address']))) ;
}
```

Trim the value.

Comment: `.` is not the member access operator in PHP, and strings have no properties in PHP, and that condition is incorrect regardless. Try `strlen(trim($_POST['address'])) === 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider regular expressions.  I would start off using a split command: `split(' ', $address)`.
From that point, you can add one extra `else if` statement to test and see if the resultant string is empty.
BUT, more importantly, you will now have the tools to test the **entire** address string to see if it contains: a two letter state code followed by a comma, and a 5(or9) digit zip code.
(I can be more specific if you like.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['submit']){
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    if (empty($address)) {
        echo "You must enter an address";
    } else {
        $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, strip_tags($user_address)) ;
    }
}
```

You can echo immediately the message if the field address is empty

also the `$_POST['submit']` is to determine if the user click the submit button